# What happens to the electric field and the potential difference in a capacitor when the distance between the plates is doubled?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, voltage

I'm not sure if I can apply Coulomb's law here to find the electric field and then the voltage change and any insight into this predicament would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Coulomb's law is a bad idea. I can be done, but Gauss's law or the definition of capacitance, combined with the relationship between electric potential and field, are much better ideas.

Comment: A question phrased this way is almost always assuming a parallel plate geometry (and in an intro class that the separation is small compared to the other linear dimensions of the device even when doubled), but it helps to be explicit about these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Constant surface charge density**

In this part of the answer I will write the answer under the assumption of constant surface charge density. This means two plates which change neither their area nor the amount of charge they can store.

The electric field between parallel plates is given by

$$ \vec E = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} \hat{r},$$

where $\hat r$ points from the positive to the negative plate. So the E field remains the same. Voltage has the relationship

$$ \Delta V = \vec E \cdot \Delta \vec l $$

So doubling the distance will double the voltage.

**Constant voltage**

More practically we have capacitors connected to batteries, in which case the voltage is fixed due to Faraday-Lenz law,

$$ \oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec l = -\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt} = 0, $$

indicating that the voltage around a closed loop is zero. In a simple circuit with just a capacitor and battery, the voltage of the capacitor has to be $-V_{\rm batt}$ per this law.

In that case, when separating the plates, the surface charge density has to change. The capacitance is

$$ C = \frac{Q}{V} = \frac{\kappa\epsilon_0 A}{d}; $$

as a result

$$ Q = \frac{\kappa\epsilon_0 A}{d} V. $$

With $V$ constant, doubling the distance will reduce, by half, the surface charge and surface charge density. As a result, the electric field

$$ \vec{E} = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} \hat{r} $$

is also halved.

Comment: @JulzerinoSzach Due to the downvote and now that I am on a computer (and can properly type), I have edited my answer with much more detail.

Comment: @zhutchens1 your answer is technically incorrect: in $\vec E=\sigma/\epsilon_0$ the left hand side is a vector and the right hand side a scalar, so the two *cannot* be equal.  Either you need to transform $\vec E$ into a scalar or make the right hand side a vector.

Comment: @zhutchens1.  I have no idea why you would think my comment was harsh or pedantic, or would discredit your entire post, especially as you’ve just admitted your original answer was obviously sloppy.  It has certainly improved but since you do not specify the direction of $\hat r$ there is yet room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it depends. If you disconnect the capacitor before changing the separation then the charge is held fixed. If you leave it attached to a battery, on the other hand, the voltage is held fixed. In either case, the capacitance
$$C=\epsilon\frac{A}{d}$$
will be cut in half by a doubling in $d$. Thus, if charge is held fixed then we can use the definition of capacitance, $Q=CV$, to get
\begin{align}
Q_{\mathrm{initial}}&=Q_{\mathrm{final}}\\
C_{\mathrm{initial}} V_{\mathrm{initial}} &= C_{\mathrm{final}} V_{\mathrm{final}} \Rightarrow \\
V_{\mathrm{final}} &= \frac{C_{\mathrm{initial}}}{C_{\mathrm{final}}}V_{\mathrm{initial}} = 2 V_{\mathrm{initial}}.
\end{align}
To get the electric field, just use the fact that the electric field is constant in a capacitor (as long as $d$ is the smallest dimension of the capacitor by a good amount) to get that $V=Ed$.

In the case where the battery holds the voltage fixed, go straight to $V=Ed$ in an analogous manner.

Answer (score -1):

C=Q/V;
E=Q/E0A;
V=Ed = Qd/E0A;
C=Q/V=E0A/d;

Thus C will be half on doubling the distance and voltage will be doubled .

Answer (score -2):

Suppose Electric field is 'E' and potential difference (voltage) = 'V' and the distance between plates = d .

E = V / d .

Now distance is doubled , means D = 2d .

Therefore , E' = V / D = V/2d = (1/2)(V/d) = (1/2)E .

This means electric field will be halved .

Comment: And what about the voltage?

Comment: This is wrong. The electric field between parallel plates depends only on the surface charge density on the plates. Thus if you increase the distance between the plates, the electric field remains constant assuming you are not fixing the potential difference between them.

Comment: C = Q/V; E = Q/E0A; V = Ed = Qd/E0A; C = Q/V = Q/(Qd/E0A) = E0A/d; this means doubling the distance will half the capacitance and double the voltage;

Comment: This answer assumes that the capacitor is connected to a voltage source, while the other answers assumed it to be disconnected. The OP did not make any assumptions so both type of answers are possible.